# Rails 4 how to include polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a `Webcam` model which has many `Urls`

```
class Webcam < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :urls, -> {  where('kind LIKE ?','preview_url')}, :as => :urlable, :dependent => :destroy

  has_one :preview_url, -> { where('kind LIKE ?', 'preview_url') }, :as => :urlable, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'Url'

end

class Url < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :urlable, polymorphic: true

end
```

So `Webcam.joins(:preview_url).where(:id=>cam_ids)` does work, but I still have a sql call for each cam.

```
  Url Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls" WHERE "urls"."urlable_id" = $1 AND "urls"."urlable_type" = $2 AND (kind LIKE 'preview_url') AND "urls"."kind" = $3  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["urlable_id", 9756], ["urlable_type", "Webcam"], ["kind", "preview_url"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls" WHERE "urls"."urlable_id" = $1 AND "urls"."urlable_type" = $2 AND (kind LIKE 'preview_url') AND "urls"."kind" = $3  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["urlable_id", 9756], ["urlable_type", "Webcam"], ["kind", :preview_url]]
  Url Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls" WHERE "urls"."urlable_id" = $1 AND "urls"."urlable_type" = $2 AND (kind LIKE 'preview_url') AND "urls"."kind" = $3  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["urlable_id", 9759], ["urlable_type", "Webcam"], ["kind", "preview_url"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls" WHERE "urls"."urlable_id" = $1 AND "urls"."urlable_type" = $2 AND (kind LIKE 'preview_url') AND "urls"."kind" = $3  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["urlable_id", 9759], ["urlable_type", "Webcam"], ["kind", :preview_url]]
  Url Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls" WHERE "urls"."urlable_id" = $1 AND "urls"."urlable_type" = $2 AND (kind LIKE 'preview_url') AND "urls"."kind" = $3  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["urlable_id", 9760], ["urlable_type", "Webcam"], ["kind", "preview_url"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "urls".* FROM "urls" WHERE "urls"."urlable_id" = $1 AND "urls"."urlable_type" = $2 AND (kind LIKE 'preview_url') AND "urls"."kind" = $3  ORDER BY "urls"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["urlable_id", 9760], ["urlable_type", "Webcam"], ["kind", :preview_url]]
```

How can I avoid these many sql calls?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.includes(:urls, :preview_url)` (not `.joins`) to avoid `N+1` queries problem (see [Rails Guides on the topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)).

You should also have a separate `urls.kind` value for `preview_url` because you can't distinguish it from other `urls` now.

Comment: I changed it to .includes(:urls, :preview_url) and get:  Unused Eager Loading detected
  Webcam => [:urls, :preview_url]
  Remove from your finder: :includes => [:urls, :preview_url]